# Set AMS Euler as the default maths font (XeTeX)

Tags: xetex, plain-tex, amsfonts, euler

I am trying to use the AMS Euler fonts in my plain XeTeX document, and by taking inspiration from various sources online (including Knuth's macros for *Concrete Mathematics*), I thought the following would work

```
\font\teneurm=eurm10
\textfont0=\teneurm
$a$
\bye
```

(Of course there are more sizes and families to define, but this is a MNWE)

What did I do wrong?

Comment: \textfont1 not 0

Comment: @Slurp You're right, is there a table to find out which number goes with which font?

Comment: This information is stored in the \math code of a character. When you do ```\mathcode`\A``` you get `7141` in hex, which means that it's a math character of class 7 (variable) and located in family 1 (\textfont1, \scriptfont1, etc) at position `0x41`. (Class 7 means that when \fam is legal (0-15), the family specified by \fam is used instead of family 1. This is how macros like \rm and \cal work in math mode).

Comment: @Slurp Thanks for your answer, I will experiment a bit with this. It would be convenient if there was already some eulerfonts.tex file to import

Comment: Sure, let me expand on this a bit more in a formal answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to change the look of `a` in math mode, it is necessary to change family 1 of fonts (`\textfont1`, `\scriptfont1`, and `\scriptscriptfont1`). To understand why this is, it's necessary to understand how TeX knows how to correctly typeset a character in math mode. Compared to text mode, there are far more fonts in use within math mode. So while in text mode it is (usually) sufficient to simply look at the character in the current font at a specific location, this is not the case for math mode.

Instead TeX utilizes the mathcode of the character, which you can access with, for example, `` \the\mathcode`\a ``, which prints `29025`. Converting this into hex you get `7161`. To unpack a mathcode:

- The first number (in the hexadecimal representation) is called the *class*. The class of a character dictates the spacing rules for it.
- The next number is the *family*, this is the font family where the character is stored.
- The next two numbers is the location of the character within the font.

In this case, where family=1 and location=61, we can see that when looking at the font table for `cmmi10` (`\textfont1`):

[image: font table for cmmi10]

At place `0x61` is the italic `a` character.
So in order to change the font used for the `a` character, you must change font family 1.

---

---

That answers the question about changing the font of a character in math, but I didn't really explain what the class of a character means. This isn't really important to know for your question, but it is useful in general.

There are 8 classes (which a character can be):

0. Ordinary: these are characters like `/`.
1. Large Operator: these are characters like `\sum` and `\int`, they are special in that they are vertically centered and have limits (material which goes above and below them).
2. Binary Operation: these are characters like `+`.
3. Relations: these are characters like `=`.
4. Opening: these are characters like `(`.
5. Closing: these are characters like `)`.
6. Punctuation: these are characters like `,`.
7. Variable: these are mainly letters and numbers.

(There is one more type of class, but it can't be in the value of a `\mathcode`: the Inner Formula class. These are usually generated by `\left...\right` constructs.)

While the main use of these classes is for spacing, some classes have special properties as well, specifically the Big Operator (1) and Variable (7) classes. Big operators are vertically centered and have *limits* (material which goes above and below them), this is why you can do `\sum_{n=1}^\infty` and get `n=1` below and `\infty` above the `\sum`.

But `a` is of the Variable class. The Variable class has no special spacing rules, the rules for an Ordinary class are used; it is almost identical to the Ordinary class except for in one important respect. The family used by a Variable character is dictated by a register `\fam`, when `\fam` is a valid family (between 0 and 15), the family used is `\fam` instead of whatever is specified in the `\mathcode` of the character. This is what allows for changing fonts in math mode without changing the values of `\textfont` and friends. For example, since family 0 is the family of roman fonts, plain TeX defines `\rm` like

```latex
\def\rm{\fam\z@\tenrm}
```

ie. it both sets `\fam` to 0 (`\z@` is a register which is always zero) and also changes the current font to `cmr10`. Changing `\fam` in text mode doesn't change anything (TeX also automatically sets `\fam` to -1 when math mode is entered, so this really has no effect), and `\tenrm` has no effect in math mode. So both of these are necessary in order for `\rm` to work both in text mode and math mode.

Further information can be found in the TeXbook (like the exact spacing rules used, and how TeX typesets other special characters in math mode like delimiters and accents).

Comment: This is a very detailed answer, thank you very much for your time, I will study it in details